# Run a c# code and sql database without Visual Studio and SQL Studio Manager

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I have been writing an application using Visual Studio and MySQL Management Studio. The application is nearly complete, and I want to package it into a standalone file (or files) that can be used without Visual Studio etc. How do I do this?

Comment: Check the `bin` output folders, it should contain the appropiate assemblies

Comment: Sounds like they are having trouble compiling?

Comment: I have tried to rephrase the question as best I can interpret it; if I have misunderstood the problem, please can you rephrase it? Feel free to revert my edit, but please understand that the original question was **very** hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Build your projects in Release mode. Check out the bin/Release folder.

Comment: Does this handle the mySql database as well? Does it contain for example  a stand-alone instance?

Comment: @Stefan no. you're going to have to have the database hosted someplace. Either on an in house server or in the cloud. Cloud solutions are very cheap. I run a website on Azure (C# + SQL Server) and it costs about $75/mo. You could go with a completely free plan as well. AppHarbor is also very cheap, you could probably get that down to $10/mo or so...

Comment: there's no other way to make them on executable file?

Comment: @CopenhagenLlagas: yes, there is something which is called LocalDb, it might be suited for presentation purposes as well although I am not sure if you can "bake" this in your executable. It's targetting ms-sql by the way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For database you can set [DatabaseInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx)  if you use EntityFramework. It create your db if it doesn't exist.